# How to completely disable macros in the Excel 2013 C# Api

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2013, vba

I have an application that uses Excel 2013. I need a way to disable all macros. I can not do it on workbook open because I do not have access to the open methods, the workbook is opened by another COM application then passed to me. It needs to happen prior to opening the document. What I am ultimately trying to do is set the setting found in the image below.

[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837822.aspx

Comment: While yes it looks like that will work. I am really looking for a solution that will persist the setting after application restart. According to that documentation "This property is automatically set to msoAutomationSecurityLow when the application is started". The setting shown in the image above can be set manually and seems to persist. That is why what I am really looking to do is just set that property through the C# API

Comment: The above solution did not work due to the fact that I do not have access to the Excel start code. I tried starting the app, setting the AutomationSecurity property and leaving the app open then calling the second COM application to open the document. However I still get prompted with a dialog asking if i want to enable macros

Comment: I'd look in the registry (at least on Windows) - likely you could change the value there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found was to edit the registry. Shout out to Tim Williams for pointing me in the right direction

The key that needs to be edited is
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Security\VBAWarnings

In my case I was to disable all macros by setting the value to 4

More info can be found [Here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/diana_tudor/2014/12/02/microsoft-project-how-to-control-macro-settings-using-registry-keys/)