# How do I open an Excel macro-enabled workbook from Python WITHOUT enabling macros?

Tags: python, vba, excel, win32com

I am trying to quickly read through a bunch of Excel reports using a Python program. The problem is that because of the software used to create these Excel files, they are all macro-enabled and opening any one of them from Python will automatically enable the macros and launch the third-party software.

If I open any one of these workbooks manually, I can choose NOT to enable macros, and thereby NOT launch the third party software, but still read the report. This is what I want my Python program to do.

Is there an option using win32com.Dispatch for the Open() method that specifically states whether I want to enable macros?

Comment: Try using pandas.read_excel(file_path). I am not 100% sure, but I think it doesn't start macros and reads data from the excel file as it is. Let me know if it helps

Comment: I guess editing the registry is quite a good answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507601/how-to-completely-disable-macros-in-the-excel-2013-c-sharp-api

Comment: Does Python give you access to the Excel object model? If yes, then use `Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable` where `Application` is the `Excel.Application`.

Comment: Thank you, Cindy! That appears to have done the trick.